# ImportError: cannot import name Document

Tags: python-2.7, python-docx

When I am running

```
from docx import Document
```

I am getting error as

```
ImportError: cannot import name Document
```

I am working on Python 2.7.

Comment: Did you install the package correctly? can you import any other submodules of it? Please post a [mcve] including the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you have installed only `docx`, but I tried with this and worked for me:

`pip uninstall docx`

`pip install python-docx`

This way you will be using the newest version of the library, hope you find it useful.

Comment: When you are able to @SiddhiSawant, please click the tick/check mark to the left of this answer. Although it is not mandatory, doing so rewards the volunteer who assisted you.

Comment: Hello. This did not work in my case. I have docx-python instaled and I still get this error message. Any suggestions? Also If I run import from cmd there is no error